# Punteros int **, en c++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    int **test;
    int var[3][3]={{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{17,18,19}};   
    **test=var[0][0];
    cout<<*test;

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Al compilar me sale el error de que test no esta inicializada. Como se inicializa una variable int **?

Answer (score 5):

Los punteros sirven para apuntar<sup>1</sup> a datos en memoria. Un puntero a entero (`int *`) apunta a datos `int`, un puntero a un puntero a entero (`int **`) apunta a datos `int *`, que a su vez apuntan a datos `int`. Es decir, en memoria tendría un aspecto parecido a esto:

[image]

Fíjate que `var` (que es `int **`) apunta a otros datos (que son `int *`) que a su vez apuntan a otros datos (que son `int`). ¿Qué pasa en el caso de `test`? en memoria tendría un aspecto parecido a esto:

[image]

La variable `test` no apunta a ningún sitio porque no le hemos dado ningún sitio al que apuntar, por lo tanto `*test` ni siquiera sabemos dónde está y menos aún `**test`. Eso es lo que te está diciendo el error.

No necesitas copiar el primer elemento del primer elemento de `var` en el inexistente primer elemento del primer elemento de `test`, debes hacer que `test` apunte al mismo sitio que `var`, para ello haz que `test` sea un puntero a tres enteros (`int[3]`):

```
int (*test)[3];
```

Después podrás igualar ambas variables:

```
test=var;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U9swFW1zjm3vqjPY).

---

1. [Gracias, capitán obviedad](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50400906#50400906).

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos errores:

### Asignación de punteros

NOTA: Por simplicidad, solo usaré `int *` y no `int **`, pero la idea es la misma solo con un nivel más de indirección.

Cuando haces `*puntero` no estás tratando con el puntero, sino con la posición de memoria a la que apunta (se dice que *dereferencias el puntero*).

Así que si haces

```
int *test;
*test = 10;
```

Estás asignando el 10 a una posición de memoria sin determinar.

Si quieres asignar la posición de memoria, usa la variable sin derreferenciar (sin el *).

```
int *test;
int a[] = {10, 11, 12};
test = a;
```

y para comprobar el efecto

```
*test = 42; // En la primera posición del array pones un 42 en vez del 10 que había antes
printf("%i\n", a[0]);
```

Si haces `*test` antes de asignar un valor a *test*, la dereferencia es ilegal y es un *undefined behavior*.

### Puntero a array bidimensional

En C, una variable array es equivalente un puntero al inicio del array (el compilador añade la lógica para poder acceder mediante índices). Y un array multidimensional es un puntero al tipo que lo define. Así que para asignar *var*  a un puntero, este debe ser `int *`, no `int **`.

Con todo lo dicho, debería quedarte:

```
int *test;
int var[3][3]={{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{17,18,19}};   
test= &var[0][0]; // Puntero al inicio del array
cout << *test << endl; // Imprime 11
```

Comment: Tu propuesta no compila, a `test` (de tipo `int *`) no se le puede asignar el valor de `var` (de tipo `int[3][3]`).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster solucionado, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El puntero a puntero "test" debe tener alguna dirección de memoria guardada (que sea del programa); por esa razón el compilador te lanza error. Además de eso, "test" tendría por defecto contenido basura y que podría coincidir con alguna dirección de memoria ocupada por el sistema y hacer que el programa aborte su ejecución. 
Lo ideal sería hacer algo como esto:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int* px = &x;
    int **test = &px;
    int var[3][3]={{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{17,18,19}};   
    **test=var[0][0];
    cout<<**test; //Imprimimos el nuevo contenido de la variable "x".

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Claro, sólo fue un simple ejemplo, el puntero doble deberá recibir la dirección de memoria de un puntero, acuérdate que un puntero a puntero tiene dos niveles de direccionamiento indirecto (como decir, dos "trayectorias").